# Need help separating unorganized JSON/JSON arrays

Tags: mysql, json

Ok so I don't necessarily understand this or how to do this at all but I am either looking for something that will show me how to sit there and split this portion of MYSQL json into either separate rows or just a way to export as either csv or json and then split one portion off from the others

Example of the JSON:

[{"id":2, "identifier":"IDENTIFIER:", "license":"LICENSE:", "firstname":"FIRSTNAME", "lastname":"LASTNAME", "accounts":"{"money":9595,"bank":9595}"},
{"id":2, "identifier":"IDENTIFIER", "license":"LICENSE", "firstname":"FIRSTNAME", "lastname":"LASTNAME", "accounts":"{"black_money":9595,"bank":9595,"money":9595}"}]

I want to be able to separate the three things in the JSON array called accounts this is all held in a mysql DB and I want to either be able to run something and have a exportable table that can be imported into google sheets or something of that sort so I can sort them if need be.

Comment: Hi ! It seems it's not valid JSON, you can test it here before anything else :
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that your json is probably like

> [{"id":2, "identifier":"IDENTIFIER:", "license":"LICENSE:", "firstname":"FIRSTNAME", "lastname":"LASTNAME", "accounts":"{\"money\":9595,\"bank\":9595}"}, {"id":2, "identifier":"IDENTIFIER", "license":"LICENSE", "firstname":"FIRSTNAME", "lastname":"LASTNAME", "accounts":"{\"black_money\":9595,\"bank\":9595,\"money\":9595}"}]

but when copying / pasting the backslashes disappeared. Your json is obviously special since it includes other json. Try

```
function myFunction() {
  var json = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue()
  var data = JSON.parse(json)
  var result = []
  result.push(['account.black_money','account.bank','account.money'])
  data.forEach(function(elem){
    var account = JSON.parse(elem.accounts)
    result.push([account.black_money,account.bank,account.money])
  })
  return result
}
```

take a copy of : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NwSUF7hRNjcLRbr2HP_mjj-fPfbKJz7BNLYFr184P4o/copy

Comment: so when it came to this stuff I pulled it directly from a mysql table and exported it to be JSON.